# Is there a way, using streaming in the browser, to toggle the video stream on/off?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, streaming, html5-audio, icecast

**The current setup**
I'm building a web application which will basically act as an internet radio, but with optional video content too.
The server will be using Icecast to provide the stream (although if required, I could definitely use something else).

**The question**
Is it possible to implement something, that would allow the user to seamlessly switch the video stream on or off, where the audio will keep playing uninterrupted, and both streams will stay synchronised too.

Synchronisation is only important per-client, not between clients. I don't mean just hiding the video stream either, the idea is to minimize bandwidth usage when not watching.

Watching the stream will happen from within the browser and I do not want to use something like a java plugin.

Support for older browsers doesn't matter, the latest versions of Edge, Safari, Chrome and Firefox is enough.

Comment: this won't work with muxed content, as there you end up always with the full bitstream. The most could be to try make the browser not render the video, but I'm not aware of such functionality personally. And as you expect uninterrupted and sync'd switching from `<video>` to `<audio>` is not an option either.

Comment: @TBR what about MPEG-DASH? Of course you always find something that looks promising *after* you asked the question haha. But from what I can find, using DASH this might be possible. I'm going to try writing some code to test the idea, if it works I'll post it here as an answer.

Comment: yes, DASH or HLS might work, but that's no longer Icecast territory  and I can't help with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't possible to do the way I wanted to (actually turn off the video stream).

Next best workaround is by using DASH and adding effectively an empty (or just black) video stream that can be switched to.